# Cloning an app which generates code with toolbars, pre-defined components and an art-board

Tags: node.js, angular, user-interface

I need to clone a website i.e builderx.io which sort of has a figma/sketch like working structure, there are toolbars with functionalities such as styling, border, effects, layout. It also has pre-defined collection of components to choose from such as buttons, grids, icons and more. There is an artboard where we can drag-and-drop and adjust/resize/move/copy any elements, styles and components we choose. In parallel to the design feature, it also has a code feature, where any changes in the artboard generate code in react/react-native which represents the art-board. I need to clone this entire app and generate the code in flutter, as has been done in react/react-native. The tech stack will be angular/node. But I don't have a starting point on what external libraries/tools will such a web app require keeping the exact structure and functionalities of the app in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I co-created BuilderX.

On a very high-level, you will need to build

- A tree-like data-structure to store the layers
- A renderer to convert the tree to visual elements
- A code-generator that converts the tree to Code

Then we add interactions in the renderer and code-generator.

- Interaction on the renderer would be Mouse and Keyboard Events that would make changes to the data tree and re-generate the code.
- Interaction on the code would require you to fetch the AST, make changes to it and make changes back to the tree and re-render the design.

I spoke in-depth about the approach at React Europe. The video is [up here](https://youtu.be/31pjm-ifL20).

Thanks!